# xades4j verification without KeyInfo

Tags: xml, xades4j

Our company uses Etokens to communicate with server over https. How do I verify an enveloped XML file which comes without signing certificate in the KeyInfo?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EDoc><NextMsg ID="Edoc">2019-09-23T16:20:53</NextMsg><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"></ds:SignatureMethod>
<ds:Reference Id="xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1-ref0" URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>IUdYs162QE1GdUEKUxqppoFmNvrYMLMBGnduWy6v3rc=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1-signedprops">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
<ds:DigestValue>Uw2b3fkLSJPm+yDeYwXQhJHZhWP+vUNBEeS55LcII00=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue Id="xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1-sigvalue">
eHOQcdUYRRhQa3DV+P5lWnXR32KXpO08n4QI/SIXvJxbjvz3roGNas53E/1hCui8MG3TkZulx4Fw&#xD;
W3N9qJ3FXciasReaqofrexHtbntyr6O/tzQh2akcJzo3TPH+j4PxozjFUxCxcaJRSqCE0hWdBtuI&#xD;
S8rn+EKpes7ohgtlsVg=
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:Object><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1"><xades:SignedProperties xmlns:ns3="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" Id="xmldsig-5d0f41cd-6e98-488d-9415-28b6329b34d1-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2019-09-23T16:20:53+03:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod><ds:DigestValue>woG3fsImDUeqxznickzLkpeY9R4=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>cn=LB-LITAS-CA,ou=MSD,o=Lietuvos bankas,l=Vilnius,c=LT</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>105704079740755226136574</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate></xades:SignedSignatureProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object>
</ds:Signature></EDoc>
```

Default `verify` function searches for KeyInfo

```
 public static void verifyBes(KeyStore ksaa, String path)
      throws javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException, org.xml.sax.SAXException,
          java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, xades4j.utils.XadesProfileResolutionException,
          xades4j.XAdES4jException, java.io.IOException, java.security.NoSuchProviderException,
          java.security.cert.CertificateException, java.security.cert.CRLException,
          java.security.cert.CertStoreException, java.security.KeyStoreException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File(path));
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    Element idChild = (Element) root.getFirstChild();
    DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(idChild);

    String filename =
        System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    String password = "changeit";
    ks.load(is, password.toCharArray());

    X509Certificate validate_cert = null;

    FileSystemDirectoryCertStore fsCertStore = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore("../certStore");
    Collection<? extends Certificate> allCerts = fsCertStore.getStore().getCertificates(null);
    // search for specific certificate to test agains
    for (Certificate c : allCerts) {
      X509Certificate pool_cert = (X509Certificate) c;
      System.out.println(pool_cert.getSubjectDN().getName());
      if (-1 != pool_cert.getSubjectDN().getName().indexOf("TEST CERTIFICATE"))
        validate_cert = pool_cert;
    }

    CertificateValidationProvider validationProviderMySigs =
        new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(ks, false, fsCertStore.getStore());
    XadesVerificationProfile instance = new XadesVerificationProfile(validationProviderMySigs);
    XadesVerifier verifier = instance.newVerifier();
    Element sig = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("ds:Signature").item(0);
    XAdESVerificationResult r = verifier.verify(sig, null);
  }
```

xades4j.verification.InvalidKeyInfoDataException: No X509Data to identify the leaf certificate
        at xades4j.verification.SignatureUtils.processKeyInfo(SignatureUtils.java:79)
        at xades4j.verification.XadesVerifierImpl.verify(XadesVerifierImpl.java:184)
        at com.mycompany.app.App.verifyBes(App.java:993)
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:460)

Comment: can we continue this discussion in GH? https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/175  I'd like you to test the `iss175` branch to see if it is enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL,DR;**

Currently, there's no way to do that.

**Reasons**

- xadesj4j is based on the XAdES 1.4.1 standard. On that standard, the `SigningCertificate` property requires that the signing certificate is identified within the property, but doesn't state which item corresponds to the signing certificate if there is more than one certificate reference in the property. xades4j tries to use the data on `KeyInfo` to figure it out.
- xades4j starts by doing the core XML-DSIG/cryptographic validation (which requires the singing certificate) and only after checks each qualifying property. This means that the `SigningCertificate` property isn't considered when trying to identify the certificate. Maybe this could be different, specially if there's only one certificate reference in the property (the problem mentioned in the previous item wouldn't be applicable).

**Ideas**

1. The goal of identifying the signing certificate is to supply a `X509CertSelector` to `CertificateValidationProvider.validate()`. Without other changes, if an "empty" cert selector was supplied when `KeyInfo` is not present, it would mean that the `CertificateValidationProvider` would need to know how to identify the signing certificate. The builtin `PKIXCertificateValidationProvider` would fail, which is not cool. However, since this scenario currently fails, it means that the change wouldn't breaking existing apps.
2. When there is no `KeyInfo`, try to lookup the `SigningCertificate` property and if it contains a single certificate reference, use the issuer/serial in there to configure the `X509CertSelector`. Given the current architecture, this has the downside of accessing property data prior to the core signature verification.

I'm not a fan of any of the options. I've added [a reference to this question in an existing issue](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/175) also about the creation of the`X509CertSelector`. I'll think a bit more about this. Feel free to throw in more ideas or experiment with implementation.